# Decorating a Python method already decorated with @classmethod which calls another @classmethod

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

This is a base Python question. I am trying to decorate a `@classmethod` with my own decorator, `my_decorator`. The original `@classmethod` actually calls another `@classmethod` inside. The problem comes up when calling this inner method because it depends on the `cls` argument. This would be fine if I could just replace any call like `cls.boo()` with `Foo.boo()` if my class is always `Foo`, but this is obviously not a choice when I write children classes that inherit from `Foo`. Below is what I am trying to write.

```
def my_decorator(method):
    def redefined_method(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Starting decorator')
        result = method(args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return redefined_method

class Foo(object):        
    @classmethod
    def boo(cls):
        print('Running from Foo\'s boo')

    @classmethod
    @my_decorator
    def bar(cls):
        print('Running from Foo\'s bar')
        '''
        Replacing the following line with 'Foo.boo()'
        produces no errors when calling `Foo.bar()`, 
        but then we can't run Child's version of the boo method.
        ''' 
        cls.boo()

class Child(Foo):
    @classmethod
    def boo(cls):
        print('Running from Child\'s version of boo')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Foo.bar()    
    Child.bar()
```

I expect the following output.

```
Starting decorator
Running from Foo's bar
Running from Foo\'s boo
Starting decorator
Running from Foo's bar
Running from Child\'s version of boo
```

Current output.

```
Starting decorator
Running from Foo's bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\....\dec_example.py", line 29, in <module>
    Foo.bar()    
  File "C:\....\dec_example.py", line 4, in redefined_method
    method(args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\....\dec_example.py", line 21, in bar
    cls.boo()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'boo'
```

I tried switching the order of `@classmethod` and `@my_decorator` but it still doesn't work and produces the following stacktrace.

```
Starting decorator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\....\dec_example.py", line 29, in <module>
    Foo.bar()    
  File "C:\....\dec_example.py", line 4, in redefined_method
    method(args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to unpack `args`:

```
def my_decorator(method):
    def redefined_method(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Starting decorator')
        method(args, **kwargs)
        # here ^, no star!
    return redefined_method
```

Comment: Normally you'd also return the value that `method` returns.  With this version, no return value is possible.

Comment: @TomKarzes, oops that's a typo. Nice catch.